# How to redirect HTTPS traffic to local HTTP server using mitmproxy?

Tags: networking, mitmproxy

I am trying to setup mitmproxy so that I can make a request from my browser to `https://{my-domain}` and have it return a response from my local server running at http://localhost:3000 instead, but I cannot get the https request to reach my local server.  I see the debugging statements from mitmproxy.  Also, I can get it working for http traffic, but not for https.

I read the [mitmproxy addon docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-overview/) and [api docs](https://mitmproxy.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.2/scripting/api.html#mitmproxy.http.HTTPRequest)
I've installed the cert and I can monitor https through the proxy.

I'm using Mitmproxy: 4.0.4 and Python:    3.7.4

This is my addon (**local-redirect.py**) and how I run mitmproxy:

```py
from mitmproxy import ctx
import mitmproxy.http

class LocalRedirect:

  def __init__(self):
    print('Loaded redirect addon')

  def request(self, flow: mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow):
    if 'my-actual-domain-here' in flow.request.pretty_host:
      ctx.log.info("pretty host is: %s" % flow.request.pretty_host)
      flow.request.host = "localhost"
      flow.request.port = 3000
      flow.request.scheme = 'http'

addons = [
  LocalRedirect()
]
```

```sh
$ mitmdump -s local-redirect.py | grep pretty
```

When I visit the url form my server, I see the logging statement, but my browser hangs on the request and there is no request made to my local server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above addon was fine, however my local server did not support HTTP2.

Using the `--no-http2` option was a quick fix:

```sh
mitmproxy -s local-redirect.py --no-http2 --view-filter localhost
```

or

```sh
mitmdump -s local-redirect.py --no-http2 localhost
```

Comment: How did you ever had it work? For me, `request` isn't called during `CONNECT` requests (which Chrome sends for https:// URLs when using a proxy.)

Comment: @IlyaSemenov mitm uses port `8080` by default.  Did u [install the cert](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/) and configure chrome correctly

Comment: Of course I did. The requests *are* coming through mitmdump (and the plugin), but `request` callback isn't called for https pages (it is for http pages). mitmproxy logs `CONNECT` (rather than `HTTP GET`) requests coming from Chrome when accessing https pages. Anyway, I switched to reverse proxy mode for my purposes.

Comment: I have the same issue, but with an app I'm working on. So is this a thing that only happens when a proxy is active?